# Add PoA authorities when the chain is started

Tags: substrate

I'm new in substrate and I followed "Start a Private Network" ( https://substrate.dev/docs/en/tutorials/start-a-private-network/ ) and "Build a permissioned network" ( https://substrate.dev/docs/en/tutorials/build-permission-network/ ) guides, now I want to add more nodes (adding aura and grand keys) that can generate and finish blocks, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no integrated way to update authorities integrated in the node template so you need to update your chainspec, purge the chain, and restart.

If you want this capability, here is one pallet that you could incorporate and modify to allow for changes via extrinsic: https://github.com/gautamdhameja/substrate-validator-set

Comment: Thanks, it sounds good but I can't get it compile I'll make an issue in github